# javascript - Getting popup message - This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

In my application I am using the following code. When I try to open the html file, I am getting the pop-up message `"This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js."`

I have imported the file AC_RunActiveContent.js. into my package and referred the same.
  Can anyone help me in fixing this?
Code is

```
<HTML>
<script language="javascript">AC_FL_RunContent = 0;</script>
<script language="javascript"> DetectFlashVer = 0; </script>
<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var requiredMajorVersion = 10;
var requiredMinorVersion = 0;
var requiredRevision = 45;
-->
</script>
<BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF">


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0 || DetectFlashVer == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
} 
else {
    var hasRightVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);
    if(hasRightVersion) { 
        AC_FL_RunContent(
            'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,45,2',
            'width', '400',
            'height', '250',
            'scale', 'noscale',
            'salign', 'TL',
            'bgcolor', '#777788',
            'wmode', 'opaque',
            'movie', 'charts',
            'src', 'charts',
            'FlashVars', 'library_path=charts_library&xml_source=sample.xml', 
            'id', 'my_chart',
            'name', 'my_chart',
            'menu', 'true',
            'allowFullScreen', 'true',
            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
            'quality', 'high',
            'align', 'middle',
            'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
            'play', 'true',
            'devicefont', 'false'
            ); 
    } else { 
        var alternateContent = 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
        + '<u><a href=http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a></u>.';
        document.write(alternateContent); 
    }
}
// -->
</script>
<noscript>
    <P>This content requires JavaScript.</P>
</noscript>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you could always try an alternative embedding method: https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning variable values to 0:

```
AC_FL_RunContent = 0; <--
DetectFlashVer = 0;   <--
```

and checking it:

```
if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0 || DetectFlashVer == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
} 
else {
....
```

So try removing top two variables, and check if your **AC_RunActiveContent.js** script is loaded or not